# Nexus 6P Bootlooping, can't go to recovery mode, tried multiple flashes, used Nexus Root Toolkit. Is my device gone forever?

Tags: recovery-mode, boot-loop, nexus-6p

As you guys may know, the Nexus 6P has a notorious bootlooping issue. After trying multiple flashes, and even going to WugFresh's Nexus Root Toolkit, I had no avail for any signs that my device was fixed. I can't go to recovery mode either because it bootloops there too. My question is that is my device gone forever? Can I no longer fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried just to run TWRP recovery from external image (not flash): `fastboot boot <twrp.img>`

Comment: Not yet, but I'll try that now.

Comment: @Robert tried that command, still bootlooping.

Comment: @user334424 did you find any solution?